# SAS Toke for Azure Blob Storage - is it possible to create a token for a file to be uploaded? Write only?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So i've got a framework working with the azurestoragejs library (2.10.102) and using the examples here:

https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html

But these tend to focus on getting a SAS for the entire container. Whereas i need to upload a large file to blob direct from browser. So i can use my middleware to generate a write only token that expires. But that's the entire container. It's fairly secure but i can't help feeling that i should be generating a sas that also uses the particular URI filename as well and locking it down to that single upload.

But nothing i've done seems to work, always fails with authentication errors.

So firstly i want to check that what i think i should be doing is actually possible - to lock a write request to a particular file. Not just lock a whole blob container? I know in reverse that's what you do, if you want to read a single file then you can create a SAS with just that file but that's an object that exists. I'm talking about a sas for an object not yet written...

---

So here's more detail.

The code is similar to the example from MS. I have 3 approaches to generate a SAS. One is hardcoded from the portal which works no problem. The one uses the library to create the SAS and that seems to work. But clearly i need the middleware to do this

```
    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                  AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: permissions,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        } 
    };
    var sasToken = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container,    blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);
```

The above doesn't seem to use the blob name (the filename of what is about to be uploaded.

thanks
Paul

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible to create a SAS token for a specific blob even if that blob doesn't exist. Please share what you have tried so far and the issues you're facing.

Comment: I'm going to update the question, more room there

Comment: Your SAS Token generation looks fine. Can you please edit your question and include the code where you're using this SAS token to upload the file and the detailed error message you're getting. If you trace the request/response, you will more details about the authentication error.

Comment: @paulinventome did you ever get this working? currently in the same boat -- I want to give the user the ability to upload up to <n> number of documents to a container.